# When I use Install-Module on a VM where are the modules being stored?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am working in Windows PowerShell in a VM. I am trying to setup everything so that I can create a Hybrid Runbook. The thing is my VM is not connected to the internet. So I download the module packages from the PowerShell gallery and have to place them in the VM. I was wondering where they should be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the modules are located here: `C:\Users\user_name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this worked for me!